# How to run a package.sls file on a minion?

Tags: salt-stack

I have a package.sls file with packages I want to test on my minion.
How can I run this file on my salt minion using the command line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a file called `mypackage.sls` in the current directory, this should execute all of the states within the file:

`sudo salt-call --local --file-root=. state.sls mypacakge`

- `--local` means run without looking for a master
- `--file-root=.` means look for state files in the current directory
- `state.sls` means execute the states in an sls file
- `mypackage` is the name of the sls file, without the .sls extension

Note that calling it this way will not have access to any sls includes or dependencies on the master.